# i want to add dynamic TextView with db's data and clickable

Tags: android, database, textview, clickable

I want to add dynamic textView that holds data from db. when I will click add button it will open next activity and feed textField data into db then return back to main activity and add inserted data into text view clickable (when click on that textView that again open activity in editable form and update that data)
///

I got data dynamic in textView but i want to clickable (open into new intent) that perticular item so that i can update perticular item into db

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentData) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case (100):
        {
            String currentId=intentData.getStringExtra(AddInvoiceItem.ItemId);
            String itemName=intentData.getStringExtra(AddInvoiceItem.ItemName);
                        customerNotes.setText(itemName);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutItem);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(itemName);

            ll.addView(tv);

}
```

Comment: What kind of issues are you facing?

Comment: ok sir i'm going to add what i have done so far

Comment: why u guys did vote down i want to know plz...then i will take care of this mistake

Comment: i need to textVIew clickable with perticular id

Comment: i got the solution..

Answer (score 0):

```
final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutItem);
    //LinearLayout layoutSection = new LinearLayout(this);
final   RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramss = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    //params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    params.setMargins(50,0,0,0);// left, top, right, bottom
    paramss.setMargins(400, 0, 0, 0);
    params.height=60;
    params.width=200;
    final   ImageView imageView=new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.remove);


final   TextView textView = new TextView(this);
final       TextView tv=new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    tv.setLayoutParams(paramss);
    textView.setText(itemName);
    textView.setTextSize(18);
    tv.setText(total);

    ll.addView(rl);
    rl.addView(imageView);
    rl.addView(textView);
    rl.addView(tv);

textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent updateItem=new Intent(this,second.class);
                              updateItem.putExtra("type","item");



            this.startActivityForResult(updateItem, 100);

            }
        });
        }
```

put it in your onActivityResult i code as per ur requirement..